# Running FireBase in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios4, firebase

Hi I am trying to run FireBase in the background.

I have the following code:
The code does the following
- When the app goes in the background, it keeps checking Firebase for new chat messages. It then increments the application badge number if new chat messages are found.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    NSLog(@"in background fetching8");

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports mulitasking
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance


            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object
            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid
                //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
            }];


            //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                //Perform your tasks that your application requires


                NSLog(@"in background fetching98");

                inBackGround = YES;

                [self fetch];


                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
            });
        }
    }


    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

fetch:

```
- (void) fetch
{
    if([[API sharedInstance] isAuthorized])
    {

        NSLog(@"in background fetching");

        Firebase * ref = nil;

        NSDictionary * investor = [[API sharedInstance] investor];
        NSDictionary * startup = [[API sharedInstance] startup];

        if(investor != nil) {

            NSInteger iid = [[API sharedInstance] userid];
            NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"http://example.firebaseIO.com/investor/%d/conversations", iid];

            ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:path];
        }
        else if(startup != nil)
        {
            NSInteger sid = [[startup objectForKey: @"id"] intValue];
            NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"http://example.firebaseIO.com/startup/%d/conversations", sid];
            ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:path];
        }


        if(ref)
        {

            NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://kickcircle.firebaseIO.com/conversations"];
            Firebase * conv = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: path];

            [ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

                // name of conversation
                NSString * name = snapshot.name;
                Firebase * ref1 = [conv childByAppendingPath: name];

                [ref1 observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {


                    if(snapshot.value != [NSNull null] && ![snapshot.value isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
                    {


                        NSLog(@"in background fetching7");

                        FDataSnapshot * chatsnapshot = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath: @"chats"];

                        NSInteger numChatMessages = chatsnapshot.childrenCount;
                        numberOfTotalChatMessages += numChatMessages;

                        NSMutableDictionary *m = [snapshot.value mutableCopy];
                        [m setValue: snapshot.name forKey: @"ref_name"];

                        // number of messages read for that conversation
                        NSInteger current_user = [[API sharedInstance] userid];
                        NSString * userpath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"users/%d", current_user];
                        FDataSnapshot * usersnapshot = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath: userpath];

                        if(usersnapshot.value != [NSNull null] && ![usersnapshot.value isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
                        {
                            NSDictionary * userdict = usersnapshot.value;
                            NSInteger numUserMessagesRead = [userdict[@"numOfMessages"] intValue];

                            if(numChatMessages > numUserMessagesRead)
                            {
                                if([[m objectForKey: @"last_from_id"] intValue] != [[API sharedInstance] userid])
                                {
                                    [m setValue: @"true" forKey: @"bubble"];

                                    newChats = YES;

                                    if(inBackGround)
                                    {
                                        [self addNotification];
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    numUserMessagesRead = numChatMessages;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                numUserMessagesRead = numChatMessages;
                            }

                            numberOfMessagesRead += numUserMessagesRead;

                            [m setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: numUserMessagesRead] forKey: @"numMessagesRead"];
                        }
                        else {

                            if([[m objectForKey: @"last_from_id"] intValue] != [[API sharedInstance] userid])
                            {
                                [m setValue: @"true" forKey: @"bubble"];

                                newChats = YES;

                                [m setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0] forKey: @"numMessagesRead"];


                                if(inBackGround)
                                {
                                    [self addNotification];
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                numberOfMessagesRead += numChatMessages;

                                [m setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: numChatMessages] forKey: @"numMessagesRead"];
                            }
                        }

                        [m setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: numChatMessages] forKey: @"numChatMessages"];

                        [self.chats addObject: m];

                        [self calculateChatNumber];

                        NSNumber * index = [NSNumber numberWithInt: self.chats.count - 1];
                        [read setValue: index forKey: snapshot.name];

                        PLRightMenuViewController * rightPanel = (PLRightMenuViewController *) self.viewController.rightPanel;
                        [rightPanel.tableView reloadData];


                    }

                }];

            }];


            [ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildChanged withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

                NSString * name = snapshot.name;
                Firebase * ref1 = [conv childByAppendingPath: name];

                [ref1 observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
                {

                    if(snapshot.value != [NSNull null] && ![snapshot.value isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
                    {

                        NSLog(@"in background fetching8");

                        NSMutableDictionary *m = [snapshot.value mutableCopy];
                        [m setValue: snapshot.name forKey: @"ref_name"];

                        numberOfTotalChatMessages += 1;


                        if([read objectForKey: snapshot.name])
                        {
                            NSInteger index = [[read objectForKey: snapshot.name] intValue];

                            // number of current chats for conversation
                            NSInteger numChats = [[[self.chats objectAtIndex: index] objectForKey:  @"numChatMessages"] intValue];

                            // number of messages read
                            NSNumber * readMessages = [[self.chats objectAtIndex: index] objectForKey:  @"numMessagesRead"];
                            NSInteger readMessagesInt = [readMessages intValue];

                            NSInteger current_user = [[API sharedInstance] userid];
                            NSString * userpath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"users/%d", current_user];
                            FDataSnapshot * usersnapshot = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath: userpath];

                            if(usersnapshot.value != [NSNull null] && ![usersnapshot.value isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
                            {
                                NSDictionary * userdict = usersnapshot.value;
                                NSInteger numUserMessagesRead = [userdict[@"numOfMessages"] intValue];

                                if([[m objectForKey: @"last_from_id"] intValue] != [[API sharedInstance] userid]) {

                                    newChats = YES;

                                    [m setValue: @"true" forKey: @"bubble"];

                                    if(numUserMessagesRead > readMessagesInt) {

                                        numberOfMessagesRead += numUserMessagesRead - readMessagesInt;

                                        readMessagesInt = numUserMessagesRead;


                                        if(inBackGround)
                                        {
                                            [self addNotification];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    numberOfMessagesRead += numChats + 1 - readMessagesInt;
                                    readMessagesInt = numChats + 1;
                                }

                            }
                            else {

                                if([[m objectForKey: @"last_from_id"] intValue] != [[API sharedInstance] userid])
                                {
                                    [m setValue: @"true" forKey: @"bubble"];
                                    newChats = YES;


                                    if(inBackGround)
                                    {
                                        [self addNotification];
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    numberOfMessagesRead += numChats + 1 - readMessagesInt;
                                    readMessagesInt = numChats + 1;
                                }
                            }

                            [self.chats removeObjectAtIndex: index];

                            [m setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: numChats + 1]  forKey: @"numChatMessages"];
                            [m setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: readMessagesInt] forKey: @"numMessagesRead"];


                            [self.chats addObject: m];

                             NSNumber * index1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: self.chats.count - 1];
                            [read setValue: index1 forKey: snapshot.name];
                        }

                        [self calculateChatNumber];

                        PLRightMenuViewController * rightPanel = (PLRightMenuViewController *) self.viewController.rightPanel;
                        [rightPanel.tableView reloadData];
                    }


                }];

            }];
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it is not working (the badge is not incrementing when there is a new message) when the app goes in the background. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The method with which you are trying to run in the background is reserved for background task completion - really it is not meant for operational execution of code. You should move to a push notification model, or wait for iOS 7 coalesced updates.

beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: signals iOS that your app would like the task to complete even if the app is moved into the background state, before the app becomes suspended.  endBackgroundTask: signals iOS that your app's task has completed, allowing it to move your app to the suspended state if it needs to.  If the app remains in the foreground the whole time then these calls have no effect, so it doesn't hurt to use them.

**Note that background tasks don't get free reign and don't get an indefinite period of time to complete. The "expiration handler" part of beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: is a block specifying your cleanup code if the task out lives its lifetime.  Code executing as a background task must not make any UI updates or openGL calls (as the app is offscreen).**

I think you get like 10 minutes max.